# HttpContext Null in healthcheck

Tags: asp.net-core

I implemented a network health check in a .NET Core ASP.NET WebAPI application.  The HttpContext is null in 50% of my requests.  Does anyone have an idea what would cause this?

I put headers in the health check request, which originate from a WAF.  For the requests that have a null HttpContext I cannot validate the header values.

Comment: You should not get an accurate answer to this question. First of all, you said that this will happen in 50% of requests, so you need to look further at which steps will reproduce this problem. It's possible that this is a bug in one of the methods, and after executing httpContext becomes Null. If it is determined that a specific method can reproduce the issue, then this 50% claim is not true.

Comment: 1. First disable WAF to see if the problem will be reproduced.
2. Use network in F12 to obtain http request information (.har) for analysis.
3. If you can locate which method, you can add try... catch..., or use log records.
4. Custom middleware can be created to detect the value of httpContext to further locate the problem.